# Using the autocorrelation of a signal \$f(t)\$ to identify its (longest) period?

Tags: signal-processing

Brad Osgood's book on Fourier Transforms defines the autocorrelation of a real signal \$f\$ of period \$T\$ with itself to be

$$(f \star f)(x) = \int_0^T f(y)f(y+x)\ dy$$

We can show that \$(f \star f)(x)\$ attains a maximum (which is the energy of \$f\$) at integer multiples of the period \$T\$. This suggests a method of finding the fundamental period \$T\$ of a signal: plot its autocorrelation and look for extreme values. However, as defined, I can't compute the autocorrelation unless I know \$T\$ to begin with. So what do I do in practice?

I can compute \$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y)f(y+x)\ dy\$ but this integral may not exist. Should I just choose some \$T_0\$ which is likely to be larger than \$T\$, and compute \$\int_0^{T_0} f(y) f(y+x)\ dy\$?

Comment: What searches of the literature have you performed? It took me just a second to find these: [YIN, a fundamental frequency estimator for speech and music](http://audition.ens.fr/adc/pdf/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf) and [Wiki: Pitch detection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm), for example. These discuss improvements upon a simple autocorrelation but they aren't sufficient. It took me a few seconds more to find dozens of papers elucidating out a handful of remaining issues that should be applied, as well. What have you done? I'm surprised you didn't come here with more.

Answer (score 1):

It's not integer *multiples* of the fundamental time T, but **sub-**multiples of it. So it T is 1 second, you can find autocorrelations for frequencies that have periods of 1 s, 0.5 s, 0.333 s, 0.25 s etc.

If your signal doesn't have a repeating period T, you will get 'leakage' in the FT -- some unexpected signals -- due to the fact that the FT will 'synthesize' a join between the end and beginning of the signal you use.

By choosing a long T, perhaps performing some windowing, you can a) reduce the spurious signals (aliasing), and set a long baseline period in order to get find resolution of the submultiples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain that in more detail? Since $f$ is periodic with period $T$, $(f \star f)(mT) = (f \star f)(0)$, so the autocorrelation will equal the energy for integer multiples of $T$, no?